# Javascript get day methods return incorrect days

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to use a javascript date object to deal with automatically rolling over the days. However getting the information seems to be difficult.

```
date = new Date();
console.log(date.toISOString());
date.setTime(date.getTime() + 600000); // 10 minutes
console.log(date.toISOString());
console.log(date.getDay());
console.log(date.getUTCDay());
```

This returns

```
"2014-10-23T22:55:34.962Z"
"2014-10-23T23:05:34.962Z"
4
4
```

I have no idea why it keeps returning a day that is not even close to what the day actually is.
My current solution just takes sections of the toISOString and assigns things bassed off of that, but I do want to know why this is doing this.

Comment: I believe [reading the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods_2) is helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't come across that documentation yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Day returns the day of the week, try date instead.